# Valid ARM executable doesn't find libraries

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, libraries, dd-wrt

I cross-compiled a small Hello World program for an ARM embedded device (an Asus RT-AC68U router running DD-WRT):

```
# arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ hello.cpp -mcpu=cortex-a9 -s -o hello
```

The file seems fine:

```
# file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, 
BuildID[sha1]=5099693c31154cdd7f04c16ced5b80b1e35e625b, stripped
```

It depends on a few libraries:

```
# readelf -d hello

Dynamic section at offset 0xf08 contains 26 entries:
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
(...)
```

When I try to execute the file on the target system, I get the following:

```
# ./hello
-sh: ./hello: not found
```

If I launch execution from `ld-linux.so.3` without any other parameters, everything works:

```
# /opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 ./hello
Hello, world.
```

When listing the libraries, the file seems to be searching for libraries in the /lib folder (they are not there, they are in /opt/lib):

```
# /opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 --list ./hello
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x76dfb000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76de0000)
    libc.so.6 => /opt/lib/libc.so.6 (0x76cb2000)
    libc.so => /lib/libc.so (0x76c35000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.3 => /opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x76f20000)
```

I'm guessing the error is due to the fact that the executable when launched on its own is not finding the required shared libraries. All the required libraries are present in the /opt/lib folder and this folder is included in LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable:

```
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/lib:/usr/lib:/jffs/lib:/jffs/usr/lib:/jffs/usr/local/lib
:/mmc/lib:/mmc/usr/lib:/opt/lib:/opt/usr/lib
```

How do I get the executable to find the libraries in the right place?

Edit: I tried linking the libraries statically in the executable and the program runs fine on the target platform. However that is not a workable solution for what I want to do.

Comment: maybe you simply need to set exec permission on your binary, e.g: `chmod a+x ./hello`

Comment: @frymode Thanks, but that's not it, it's got the right flags: `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          5720 Jan 10 11:40 hello`

Comment: Is there a newline in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or is that just an artifact from copy-and-paste?

Comment: @nneonneo No, there' s no newline. I did that for readability to avoid the horizontal scroll bar. Should have put a backslash. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ld-linux.so.3` appears to be in a nonstandard location (`/opt/lib`), and it's possible that your `gcc` is specifying a different program interpreter. You can use `readelf -l <program>` to check what program interpreter your binary is expecting (under `PT_INTERP`, "Requesting program interpreter").

If the binary's program interpreter is wrong for your platform, you can specify it manually by passing `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3` to `gcc`.

Comment: @nneoneo You're a genius, that fixed it. Thanks a million. The compile command I used is as follows: `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ hello.cpp -mcpu=cortex-a9 -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/opt/lib/ld-linux.so.3 -o hello`